# Getting "Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework" when using ShapeableImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I'm able to use the `ShapeableImageView` to show cornered image but when I check the log, there are error but no idea what is it about and how to fix it. When I change the `view` into ImageView, this error no longer showing but I can't make use of the cornered image feature(`shapeAppearanceOverlay`)

This is the error log:

```
W/ResourcesCompat: Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300fc a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:556)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:160)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:125)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:104)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.inflateColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:229)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:203)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:519)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
    at d.b.a.e.v.c.a(MaterialResources.java:60)
    at com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView.<init>(ShapeableImageView.java:112)
    at com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView.<init>(ShapeableImageView.java:92)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at f.a.a.b.d.b.d(ActivityInstallerTrackerBinding.java:164)
    at f.a.a.b.d.b.c(ActivityInstallerTrackerBinding.java:158)
    at mypackage.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.kt:64)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8006)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3584)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

This is my code at line 64

```
private lateinit var binding: MyActivityBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = MyActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) << Line 64
    setContentView(binding.root)

    initView()
}
```

I tried to add `app:errorTextAppearance` to the `ShapeableImageView` as I saw that solution for this exact error but for `TextInputLayout`, but still having that error.

Edit:
Including the ShapeableImageView xml & the style

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin8"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/glRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/glLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUpload"
            tools:visibility="visible">
            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageView"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin16"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin8"
                android:fontFamily="@font/din_condensed_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/select_successful"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivRemove"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivRemove"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin16"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the style

```
<style name="roundedImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post the xml including your ShapeableImageView.  The problem is that something in your layout is including a color state list that is invalid.  That'll be somewhere in your xml, as this is inflated.  I'd also look at any drawables or color codes you're using and make sure they're all valid.  Since it works as an image view, I'd particularly look at any xml attributes imageview doesn't support that shapableimageview does.  StrokeColor stands out as a likely suspect.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have added my ShapeableImageView XML and the style I'm using for shapeAppearanceOverlay

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Add the following to the ShapeableImageView:

```
app:strokeColor="@null"
```

This stopped the logcat output for me. There appears to be an issue in the library.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Once added, the log no longer showing the error

Comment: It worked like a charm! But how did you figured it out?!?!

Comment: It' working. how did you find out?